# I have problems storing an array of arrays from a JSON file

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, nested-lists

im a programmer in training, so, im working with Unity, C# and i want to make NPCs with dialogues, those dialogues are stored in JSON files like this one:

```
{
    "name":"Test sign",
    "content":[
        ["Hay algo escrito en este cartel..."],
        ["Pulsa el botón adecuado para leer este cartel."],
        ["Acavas de leer lo que pone en el cartel."],
        ["Te relajas al saber lo que pone en el cartel."],
        ["Nunca sabrás lo que pone en este cartel."]
    ]
}
```

Im from Spain, by the way, so, i need to get specifically the "content" variable, im trying to store it in a class like this one:

```
//A class to store the definied conversation of the npc.
    public class dialog{
        public string name;
        public List<string[]> content;
    }
```

This is how i do it:

```
//We make an object where store the data from the dialog json.
        public dialog dial;

        dial = JsonUtility.FromJson<dialog>(File.ReadAllText(jsonPath));
```

Now, when trying to access it, the ressult is always the same error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
defNPC.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/NPCs/defNPC.cs:62)
```

And when trying to get it by console, i only get "Null".

I have tried changing the JSON, and using two classes:

```
{
    "name":"Test sign",
    "content":[
        {"list":["Hay algo escrito en este cartel..."]},
        {"list":["Pulsa el botón adecuado para leer este cartel."]},
        {"list":["Acavas de leer lo que pone en el cartel."]},
        {"list":["Te relajas al saber lo que pone en el cartel."]},
        {"list":["Nunca sabrás lo que pone en este cartel."]}
    ]
}
```

```
public class SingleArr{
        public string[] list;
    }


    //A class to store the definied conversation of the npc.
    public class dialog{
        public string name;
        public SingleArr[] content;
    }
```

But none of it seems to work, i am really really confused, is it really so hard to get a list of lists in here?

Sorry if i misspell something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, fixed, turned ot to be that i needded to put [System.Serialize] on top of the classes, i dont know why but looks like its needed.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://json2csharp.com/:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
    public class Root
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> content { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It keeps telling me that JsonConvert its not declared.

Comment: I am not interested on using jsonNET, or however is written, thank you anyway.